# How can I generate a user-specified quantity of random numbers using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, random

I have to create a program that prompts the user for a number of their choice.  Once they enter the number, it should generate that number of random numbers or integers.  The random integers must be between 1 and 25.  Lastly, the program should give an output stating the largest number out of those randomly generated integers.  Does anyone know how to do this? I am struggling. Thank you so much.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sx6tsygd/

Comment: What part of this is giving you trouble? Folks here tend to offer a lot more assistance when you're specific about the area that has you stumped. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Math.random() command. It generates a random number.

```
<p>Using the Math.Random command, a random number will display when the button is clicked!</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Math.random() * 25 + 1;
}
</script>
```

To make it between 1 and 25 just multiply the result of myFunction() by 25.

Comment: This does not fully answer the question, and you really should use abstracted event handling (inline is poor practice). Also, since you're not modifying HTML, `innerHTML` should be replaced by `textContent`

Comment: publish a solution unexplained and OP has not shown his effort

Comment: "*To make it between 1 and 25…*" multiply by 24 and add 1 or multiply by 25, add 1 and floor (otherwise there may still be values between 0 and 1).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a general approach you could take, in the form of a function:

```
var generateRandomNumbers = function(count, max) {
  var numbers = [];
  var lowest = max;
  var highest = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + 1;
    if (number > highest) {
      highest = number;
    } else if (number < lowest) {
      lowest = number;
    }
    numbers.push(number);
  }
  return {numbers: numbers, lowest: lowest, highest: highest};
};
```

It returns an object with 3 keys - the array of random numbers and the highest and lowest values. So...

```
var data = generateRandomNumbers(100, 25);
data.numbers; // Array of 100 random numbers between 1-25
data.lowest; // Lowest value of all of the randoms
data.highest; // Highest value of all of the randoms
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `Math.round` is usually wrong when dealing with random numbers, it creates a non-uniform distribution. If `max` is 5 you will get 1 and 5 only 1/8th of the time because your search space is only 4! `Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + 1` should work nicely. Here is a test script: `var numbers = {}, rand, max = 5; for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i += 1) { rand = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - 1)) + 1; numbers[rand] = numbers[rand] ? numbers[rand] + 1 : 1; } console.log(numbers);`

Comment: That's a nice suggestion :) I'll update my example. Wrote it in a hurry because dinner was on the table.

Comment: Why is that `Math.min` there? `Math.random()` will only generate numbers between `0` and `0.9999999...` (so never 1, but 0 can happen)

Comment: Ha! I...did not realize that the upper bound was exclusive. D'oh!